# I'm using rails 5.0.3 and devise and ruby 2.3.3 and I'm quite new to Rails

Tags: ruby

I am planning to create an application that will have several types of users with a couple shared fields and many unrelated fields. What would be my best option?

After doing some research, it seems the most common way is to use Devise + Rolify + CanCanCan/Pundit.

My question is, for each type of user, do I just create different profile models? Or would it better to create a polymorphic association for different profile models?

Comment: Can you think of a better title? This one is terrible!

Comment: You can also consider using Roles for each user - so you don't need to go into polymorphism. check the devise documentation on how to integrate Roles into the user model

Answer (score 0):

I would personally do a base user class and then have your separate extensions stay separate like the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

class Supervisor < User
end

class Employee < User
end
```

I have done this in the past and it works out very well.